# python seed() not keeping same sequence

Tags: python, random, sequence, seed

I'm using a random.seed() to try and keep the random.sample() the same as I sample more values from a list and at some point the numbers change.....where I thought the one purpose of the seed() function was to keep the numbers the same.

Heres a test I did to prove it doesn't keep the same numbers.

```
import random

a=range(0,100)
random.seed(1)
a = random.sample(a,10)
print a
```

then change the sample much higher and the sequence will change(at least for me they always do):

```
a = random.sample(a,40)
print a
```

I'm sort of a newb so maybe this is an easy fix but I would appreciate any help on this.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a sample output (from print a) for what you get and what you are expecting? Your question is a bit vague (the numbers change?) but it sounds like this function is working like I would expect it to.

Comment: It's worth noting that a subsequence of a random sample is also a random sample itself. So, you should probably just grab the 40-element sample up front, and make the 10-element one with a slice.

Comment: @PaulSeeb yes, sorry it was a little vague. I should have explained my end goal a bit more which is to go from 0 samples to the full 100 in a random order without repeats. As my sample count increases the sequence changes at some point. When I do the sample with 10 my sequence starts as [13,84,76,25...] and the one with 40 gives me [13,83,74,24...] it seems some numbers stay the same and other change at some point which seem odd to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you were to draw independent samples from the generator, what would happen would be exactly what you're expecting:

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: random.seed(1)

In [3]: [random.randint(0, 99) for _ in range(10)]
Out[3]: [13, 84, 76, 25, 49, 44, 65, 78, 9, 2]

In [4]: random.seed(1)

In [5]: [random.randint(0, 99) for _ in range(40)]
Out[5]: [13, 84, 76, 25, 49, 44, 65, 78, 9, 2, 83, 43 ...]
```

As you can see, the first ten numbers are indeed the same.

It is the fact that `random.sample()` is drawing samples *without replacement* that's getting in the way. To understand how these algorithms work, see [Reservoir Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). In essence what happens is that *later* samples can push *earlier* samples out of the result set.

One alternative might be to shuffle a list of indices and then take either 10 or 40 first elements:

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: a = range(0,100)

In [3]: random.shuffle(a)

In [4]: a[:10]
Out[4]: [48, 27, 28, 4, 67, 76, 98, 68, 35, 80]

In [5]: a[:40]
Out[5]: [48, 27, 28, 4, 67, 76, 98, 68, 35, 80, ...]
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your second option which worked just fine, although its a bummer the random.sample wont count all the way up without switching. Your first option was nice too except it gave repeats. Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: `random.sample` doesn't use reservoir sampling. It does either a partial shuffle or rejection sampling, depending on how the sample size compares to the population size.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that `random.sample` is deterministic only if the seed *and* sample size are kept constant.  In other words, even if you reset the seed, generating a sample with a different length is not "the same" random operation, and may give a different initial subsequence than generating a smaller sample with the same seed.  In other words, the same random numbers are being generated internally, but the way `sample` uses them to derive the random sequence is different depending on how large a sample you ask for.

Answer (score 4):

You are assuming an implementation of `random.sample` something like this:

```
def samples(lst, k):
    n = len(lst)
    indices = []
    while len(indices) < k:
        index = random.randrange(n)
        if index not in indices:
            indices.append(index)
    return [lst[i] for i in indices]
```

Which gives:

```
>>> random.seed(1)
>>> samples(list(range(20)), 5)
[4, 18, 2, 8, 3]
>>> random.seed(1)
>>> samples(list(range(20)), 10)
[4, 18, 2, 8, 3, 15, 14, 12, 6, 0]
```

However, that isn't how `random.sample` is actually implemented; `seed` does work how you think, it's `sample` that doesn't!

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to re-seed it:

```
a = list(range(100))
random.seed(1)  # seed first time
random.sample(a, 10)
>> [17, 72, 97, 8, 32, 15, 63, 57, 60, 83]
random.seed(1)  # seed second time with same value
random.sample(a, 40)
>> [17, 72, 97, 8, 32, 15, 63, 57, 60, 83, 48, 26, 12, 62, 3, 49, 55, 77, 0, 92, 34, 29, 75, 13, 40, 85, 2, 74, 69, 1, 89, 27, 54, 98, 28, 56, 93, 35, 14, 22]
```

But in your case you're using a generator, not a list, so after sampling the first time `a` will shrink (from 100 to 90), and you will lose the elements that you had sampled, so it won't work. So just use a list and seed before every sampling.