# When functions in random module generate same results for a given seed

Tags: python, random

We might think the functions in [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module would generate same results for a given [seed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed), but in fact it doesn't that exactly, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066235/python-seed-not-keeping-same-sequence).

The following results are expected to be reproducible, but  something different was once generated abruptly. Why?

Unfortunately I did neither log the error nor could reproduce the problem so far.

```
import random  # python 3.8.2                                                                                                       

random.seed(0)                                                                                                        
rng = range(30)                                                                                                         
seq = [random.sample(rng, random.randint(0, 3)) for _ in rng]                                                               
print(seq)
```

There are only sparse statements about [pseudo random reproducibility](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#notes-on-reproducibility). What are potential pitfalls to use *random.**, if **absolute** reproducibility is required?

Comment: Is this your entire code which produced the problem, or did you note the problem in a larger program where you were doing threading?  Note that reproducibility cannot be guaranteed with threading because the order of calls to the underlying generator can vary based on thread scheduling.

Comment: The larger program had only once produced different result. No threading. No IO except *print*. The aforementioned random seq was the sole source of input that led to the result.

Comment: If you can't reproduce it and we can't reproduce it then we probably should close the question as not reproducible. At least you can enjoy the irony that the question itself concerns reproducibility. Note that you are using the global instance of the Random class. Any other part of your program that touches this will affect the reproducibility of the sequence. If that is a concern than just instantiate your own Random instance.

Comment: The random module had been imported and used nowhere else. Sounds fair to close it.

Answer (score 2):

The questioner on your linked question misunderstood what reproducibility means. That questioner expected that `random.sample(population, x+y)` would start with the same elements as `random.sample(population, x)`, followed by `y` additional elements. There is no such requirement.

Reproducibility means that if you perform the same sequence of RNG calls with the same seed, you get the same output. `random.sample(population, x+y)` is not the same call as `random.sample(population, x)`, so there is no requirement that they produce the same output.

---

As for the `random` module's actual reproducibility guarantees, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#notes-on-reproducibility) say the following:

> #### Notes on Reproducibility
>
> Sometimes it is useful to be able to reproduce the sequences given by
>   a pseudo random number generator. By re-using a seed value, the same
>   sequence should be reproducible from run to run as long as multiple
>   threads are not running.
>
> Most of the random module’s algorithms and seeding functions are
>   subject to change across Python versions, but two aspects are
>   guaranteed not to change:
>
> - If a new seeding method is added, then a backward compatible seeder will be offered.
> - The generator’s random() method will continue to produce the same sequence when the compatible seeder is given the same seed.

Reproducibility is guaranteed from run to run, but not across Python versions, except for the `random()` call with a compatible seeder.

Comment: Understood, but how about my test case?

Comment: @sof: Your test case should produce reproducible results, as long as you don't change Python versions.

Comment: No, nothing surrounding had been changed. That's why I'm wondering.

Comment: @sof: You probably had some other bug.